# ElasticsearchDatabaseChain in langchain Index specification

Tags: elasticsearch, streamlit, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains.elasticsearch_database import ElasticsearchDatabaseChain

ELASTIC_SEARCH_SERVER = "https://elastic:pass@localhost:9200"
db = Elasticsearch(ELASTIC_SEARCH_SERVER)

llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-4", temperature=0)
chain = ElasticsearchDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm=llm, database=db, verbose=True)
```

We have this code in langchain to interact with Elasticsearch analytics database.
Is there any way we can specify the particular index and get ESquery in result?

Currently, by default it will search in all the available indexes

To get ESQuery and query searching in the specific index of elastic search

Comment: There seems to be two properties called [`include_indices` and `ignore_indices`](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/57ade13b2b9c75d2967eb13c91417c356e2c805d/libs/langchain/langchain/chains/elasticsearch_database/base.py#L43C5-L44) that can be configured.